# Дописать расширение google chrome

Tags: html

Здравствуйте подскажите как мне дописать расширение, вот есть данный код:

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "Тут названия",
 "version": "1.0",
 "description": "Тут описания",

 "permissions": [
        "http://*/*", 
        "https://*/*"
 ],

 "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

Мне в него надо внедрить мой код:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rmnw.tk/psn-market/index.php"></script>
```

Этот код делает всплывающие окна, подскажите как мне всё это объединить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день. Политика безопасности chrome не разрешает Вам брать скрипты не совпадающие с текущим origin. Вам придется выкачать этот скрипт, создать внутри проекта файл .js и подключать его уже в нужном месте. Ваша проблема не ясна, опишите ее точнее. 
В руководстве Chrome Developer - все очень хорошо и подробно описано. 
Возможно Вам стоит разобрать примеры: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples